# How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command

Tags: perl, bash, url

In shell, I need to extract specific query parameter from URI.

I tried to play around with this to get "offset" value

```
echo "/mypath/index.php?offset=20&query=uro" | perl -MURI -le 'chomp($url = <>); print URI->new($url)->query_form("offset")'
```

But it always returns just `offset=20&query=uro`

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`query_form`](http://p3rl.org/URI#uri-query_form) returns a hash, change your script to:

```
perl -MURI -le 'chomp($url = <>); print +{URI->new($url)->query_form}->{offset}'
```

In order to process multiple lines:

```
perl -MURI -nle 'print +{URI->new($_)->query_form}->{offset}'
```

Comment: What is the way to print 'offset' for each line from output, ex. I have: echo "/mypath/index.php?offset=20&query=uro \n /mypath2/index.php?offset=30&query=uro"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`URI::QueryParam`](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aQueryParam) module in addition to [`URI`](http://p3rl.org/URI).The [`query_param` method in the `URI::QueryParam` module](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aQueryParam#keys-u-query_param) gives you query parameter values.

```
echo "/mypath/index.php?offset=20&query=uro" | perl -MURI -le 'use URI::QueryParam; chomp($url = <>); print URI->new($url)->query_param(offset);'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core [`CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) module:

```
perl -MCGI=param -e 'print param("offset")' "index.php?offset=20&query=uro"
```

Comment: for a strange reason it doesn't work with piped input... It is important as I am extracting that string there

Comment: @glaz666 `CGI` expects a query as an argument to the script. You could use `echo "/mypath/index.php?offset=20&query=uro" | perl -MCGI=param -e '@ARGV=<>; print param("offset")'`